# How do i update this legacy plugin[IOS] to work with phonegap//cordova 3.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to update an old plugin i found. My Objective C skills are close to null and i was wondering if somebody could point me to a suitable guide to update this plugin. I have made a plugin.xml and installed it in my app succesfully but but the native code is way to old (phonegap 1.5)and does not work.

Would be even better if someone could help me .

This is the plugin i wanted to update for use in phonegap 3.0

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/AudioRecord

Thanks in advance for taking out time to check this out